# how to count the match number between two dataframe fast?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I'm writing some programs on calculate the match item number between two dataframes.

for example,

```
A is the dataframe as : A = pd.DataFrame({'pick_num1':[1, 2, 3], 'pick_num2':[2, 3, 4], 'pick_num3':[4, 5, 6]})


B is the answer I want to match, like:
B = pd.DataFrame({'ans_num1':[1, 2, 3], 'ans_num2':[2, 3, 4], 'ans_num3':[4, 5, 6], 'ans_num4':[7, 8, 1], 'ans_num5':[9, 1, 9]})
```

```
DataFrame A
   pick_num1  pick_num2  pick_num3  match_num
0          1          2          4          2
1          2          3          5          2
2          3          4          6          2
```

```
DataFrame B

   ans_num1  ans_num2  ans_num3  ans_num4  ans_num5
0         1         2         4         7         9
1         2         3         5         8         1
2         3         4         6         1         9
```

and I want to append a new column of ['match_num'] at the end of A.

Now I have tried to write a mapping function to compare and calculate, and I found the speed is not that fast while the dataframe is huge, the functions are below:

```
def win_prb_func(df1, p_name):
    df1['match_num'] += np.sum(pd.concat([df1[p_name]]*5, axis=1).values==df1[open_ball_name_ls].values, 1)
    return df1

def compute_win_prb(df1):
    return list(map(lambda p_name: win_prb_func(df1, p_name), pick_name_ls))

df1 = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
df1['win prb.'] = 0
result_df = compute_win_prb(df1)
```

where `pick_name_ls` is ['pick_num1', 'pick_num2', 'pick_num3'], and `open_ball_name_ls` is ['ans_num1', 'ans_num2', 'ans_num3', 'ans_num4', 'ans_num5'].

I'm wondering is it possible to make the computation more fast or smart than I did?

now the performance would is: 0.015626192092895508 seconds

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **broadcasting** instead of concatenating the columns:

```
def win_prb_func(df1, p_name):
    df1['match_num'] += np.sum(df1[p_name].values[:, np.newaxis] == df1[open_ball_name_ls].values, 1)
    return df1
```

Since `df1[p_name].values` will return an 1-D array, you have to convert it into the column vector by adding a new axis. It only takes me `0.004` second.

Comment: Really, I also tried with df1[p_name].values.reshape(-1, 1) and the performance is slightly slower than broadcasting with np.newaxis, thank u very much! Is there any possible to be faster, cause if the dataframe is up to million rows the result time would be still long.